# add some something to system look and feel in java

Tags: java, look-and-feel

I didn't like the default look and feel in java. i am using netbeans.

I wanted windows like look and feel.so i included:

```
try
{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch(Exception e) { }
```

i have 10 tabs in my frame.After user does some work in each tab(click radiobutton etc),I have to set the background of that tab.

```
tab.setBackgroundAt(j,new Color(255,0,0));//tab is JTabbedPane
```

the look and feel is ignoring the above line.I don't want to change the look and feel.

Comment: Do you say that the line tab.setBackground uses the default look and feel rather than system look and feel? A little bit more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An an alternative to changing the look and feel, you might be able to achieve something appealing by using [*Tabs With Custom Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is still [this issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5032785). Sun thought it was not a defect that you can not set a background for a JTabbedPane. Only Metal LaF seems to respect this value; Nimbus, GTK+, and even Motif draw their own background.

Try setting custom components for tabs. Maybe user-created labels will respect the background property.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting or Code Templates